# Order of json format is getting changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Order of json format is getting changed. I need the below format

```
{
"user_id": "",
"name": "",
"StDate": "07/16/2015 13:00",
"EdDate": "07/16/2015 13:00",
"detailed": [
    {
        "Stname": ""
    },
  ]
}
```

What i am getting atlast  is

```
{
"user_id" : "1",
"Detailed" : [
{
  “Stname" : ""
},
"EdDate" : "08\/19\/2015 12:25:47",
"StDate" : "08\/19\/2015 12:25:47",
“name” : "",
}
```

After getting all values i am converting to json. I am using the following code.

```
 NSError *error1;
 NSString *jsonString1;
 NSData *jsonData1 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictjson1
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];

    if (! jsonData1) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error1);
    } else {
        jsonString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"converted json string is %@",jsonString1);
    }
```

Please advice.

Comment: JSON is a dictionary-like format, so the order shoudln't matter, as you access values by key, not by index.

Comment: JSON does not have formatting like Array does. It may change.

Comment: @ anhtu i edited please check it

Comment: Well if you want to convert json to string (with specific format), you have to create your own parser.

Comment: order of json formate is not matter you just access the value for key of NSDictionary not worried about order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON has two structures: objects and arrays. Arrays are indexed by integers, and ordered. Objects are indexed by strings, and *unordered*. You can't enforce order on JSON objects; it is implementation-dependent. If you need to access object attributes in a certain order, enumerate the keys in this order in an array.